# Bad initialisation of std::vector ?

Tags: c++

This is how I declare my vector :

```
  std::vector <Link *> _components;
```

Link is this structure :

```
  struct Link
  {
    size_t targetPin;
    nts::IComponent *component;
  };
```

First to initialise it I do

```
  this->_components.reserve(2);
```

Then, when this instruction happen, it segfault

```
  this->_components[0]->component = this;
```

Got an idea ?

Comment: Change to `this->_components.resize(2);`.

Comment: Why `std::vector<Link*>` and not `std::vector<Link>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserve expands the capacity of the vector, it does not actually increase the size, and accessing a member beyond size is illegal.

```
this->_components.resize(2);
```

is what you appear to need.

If your vector has a fixed size of 2, you may want to consider using `std::array` instead.

--- EDIT ---

Your second problem is that you haven't assigned a `Link*` to any of the members. They're null pointers.

You may want `std::vector<Link>` instead of `std::vector<Link*>` unless you have `Link` objects to populate the vector with pointers to.

Comment: I already tried it , it doesn't works either.

Comment: Yeah, I just re-read the question, see the edit.

Comment: I think it got closed *because* other people missed that nuance too, it's the same one that was tripping you up, easy to miss :)